# Selenium returning no element (s)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**Question:** Why is selenium returning no elements and how can I find them?

**Background:**
I have been stuck on this issue for the last 2 days and nothing has helped. I am using Selenium with a Rails application to confirm a string exists on a URL. I use the string, xpath and URL to do so. The problem  I am facing is selenium which is failing to find *any* elements from one URL. I believe that the issue is with the website because it doesn't occur with other URLS. Is there a way to scrape this info?

**This is the data I am working with.**
String:: information about legal programs available to military families 
Domain:: https://www.americanbar.org/groups/legal_services/milvets/aba_home_front/directory-programs/ 
Xpath:: p

Through research I have...
implemented an implicit wait (45 seconds)
try / catch
searched for elements on the page, which returns an empty array (issue)
tried searching for a single element (:xpath, '//div'), which returns the following error.

```
    Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError (no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//div"}
```

**Background on program**
The application takes a string from a URL, and the xpath of the string. This information is passed to to selenium which opens the URL and searches for the string from find_elements using the xpath.

```
 require 'selenium-webdriver'
 options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
 options.add_argument('--headless')
 options.add_argument('--window-size=1280x1280')
 options.add_argument('--enable-features=NetworkService,NetworkServiceInProcess')
 driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :chrome, options: options
 driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 45 # seconds
 driver.get domain #domain is a passed argument 
 substring = selectString.to_s.squish #selectString is a passed argument 
 ...
 #xpath is a passed argument and formatted. *find_elements(:xpath => '//p')*
 driver.find_elements(:xpath => xpath).each do |r|
       ...  
       seleniumString = driver.execute_script("return arguments[0].textContent", r).squish
       if seleniumString.include? substring
         #logic
       end 
 end 
 driver.quit
```

Comment: are the elements you want to find inside one of those iframes? If so, you have to explicitly switch to that iframe to see the elements.

Comment: @titusfortner I appreciate the response, but I do not believe so. The full xpath of the string is `/html/body/main/div[2]/div[2]/section/section/div[2]/p`

Comment: The element at that xpath is the text under "About the Directory," which I could access just fine. Are you clicking on something or navigating away from the page in your `#logic` section? I highly encourage you to run this not headless so you can see what is going on. The site also has some anti-bot features which Selenium will trigger.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your xpath looks brittle.
2. Put some delay before accessing the element.

Instead use the below **xpath**

```
//h3[@class='aba-media-promo__title']//following-sibling::p
```

In code something like this

```
driver.find_element(:xpath,"//h3[@class='aba-media-promo__title']//following-sibling::p").text
```

**or**

```
driver.find_element(:xpath,"//h3[@class='aba-media-promo__title']//following-sibling::p").attribute("innerHTML")
```

print this, should give you

```
Clicking the states from the list below provides information about legal programs available to military families.

Programs listed include military legal assistance offices, legal aid and pro bono organizations, lawyer referral and information services, and military-specific programs where available.

Any of these programs may impose income-eligibility limits, provide help in only certain areas of law, or may require payment of some costs.

Programs wishing to add or update a listing should email militaryprobono@americanbar.org.
```

**PS :**

```
information about legal programs available to military families
```

This is present twice, the above solution is for the fist occurrence.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I use a simple element to search and iterate over the elements found which works with other URLS. Even with a detailed xpath, selenium still returns the same error. I have also used an implicit and explicit wait. I pasted the error below


        Selenium::WebDriver::Error::NoSuchElementError (no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//h3[@class='aba-media-promo__title']//following-sibling::p"}

Comment: put `sleep(5)` before the code and see if that helps. Also Are you launching browser in full screen mode?